# Accord.net decision tree breaks when the Decide function is used with data not found in the training set

Tags: decision-tree, accord.net

I used separate training and testing data sets to test the decision tree induced in Accord.net. But in my training data set I found out that there had been a record which had one field value which was not found in the training data set. So after creating the tree from training data, I used the "Decide" method of the tree to see the output for the record with the new value found in the testing dataset during the runtime. But the tree breaks with the following message.

"The tree is degenerated. This is often a sign that the tree is expecting discrete inputs, but it was given only real values".

Furthermore I saw in codification the integers are assigned to the distinct values in the input data. But according to what I have said above, the testing data has a distinct data value that come in between other data for the relevant field. So until that data element is met the same integers are assigned to data in both training and testing data sets when tried to codify separately. But after the newly found data element gets an integer assigned then for the similar data elements in the testing and training data gets different values thereafter. Can someone tell me how to solve these two issues?

For the clarity of the second issue I have given some sample data below. The testing data for the same column (in this case it's Qualification) contains "Diploma" as the new value not found in the training data set.

Training data for column "Qualification": High-School, Bachelor-Degree, Masters, Doctorate 
Testing data for column "Qualification": High-School, Bachelor-Degree, Diploma ,Masters, Doctorate

Comment: In machine learning, one fundamental assumption is that the training and testing set should come from similar distributions (well, unless when doing domain adaptation). In this case, the training data has absolutely zero examples of something that you know for sure will be in the testing data. If you still have the dataset that is causing the problem, I would advise opening an issue in the Accord.NET issue tracker with it to discuss what should be done in this case.

Comment: As of release 3.8.0, decision trees will default to a recursive decision method that will not throw exceptions when unknown variable values are found during the decision process.